Проблема python CTk
Сам по себе ползунок двигается как надо, но как только я сам захочу поменять его положение, то начинаются проблемы.
Вот, например, хочу песню перемотать на 2:50 саму песню, 
то он перемотает, но ползунок продолжит двигаться так, как-будто ничего и не было.
from tkinter import *
from customtkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import Scale
from pygame import mixer
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

class MusicPlayer():
    def __init__(self, window):
        # Задаем переменные
        self.music_file = None
        self.playing_state = False
        
        # Создаем окно
        window.geometry('330x150')
        window.resizable(0, 0)
        window.title('Music')
        
        # Изображения для кнопок
        # self.play_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('play.png').resize((30, 30)))
        # self.pause_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('pause.png').resize((30, 30)))
        # self.stop_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('stop.png').resize((30, 30)))
        
        # Инициализация Pygame mixer
        mixer.init()
        
        # Кнопки
        self.Slider = CTkSlider(window, from_=0, to=100, command=self.move_slider, width=300)
        self.Slider.set(0)
        self.Slider.place(x=10, y=100)
        
        self.Load = CTkButton(window, text='Load', command=self.load, width=50)
        self.Play = CTkButton(window, text='Play', command=self.play, width=50)
        self.Pause = CTkButton(window, text='Pause', command=self.pause, width=50)
        self.Stop = CTkButton(window, text='Stop', command=self.stop, width=50)
        
        # Расположение
        self.Load.place(x=10, y=20)
        self.Play.place(x=135, y=20)
        self.Pause.place(x=260, y=20)
        self.Stop.place(x=135, y=60)

    # Загрузка файлов
    def load(self):
        try:
            self.music_file = askopenfilename(filetypes=[('Audio Files', '*.wav *.ogg *.mp3')])
            if self.music_file:
                self.music_length = mixer.Sound(self.music_file).get_length()  # Получаем длину музыки
                print(f'Сейчас играет: {self.music_file}')
                mixer.music.load(self.music_file)  # Загрузка музыки при загрузке файла
                self.Slider.configure(to=mixer.Sound(self.music_file).get_length())  # Установка длины слайдера
                self.Slider.set(0)  # Сброс слайдера
        except Exception as e:
            print(f'Не удалось загрузить файл: {e}')

    # Начать играть песню
    def play(self):
        if self.music_file:
            mixer.music.play()
            
            # Начать обновление слайдера
            self.update_slider()  

    # Пауза
    def pause(self):
        if not self.playing_state:
            mixer.music.pause()
            self.playing_state = True
        else:
            mixer.music.unpause()
            self.playing_state = False
            self.update_slider()

    # Остановка
    def stop(self):
        mixer.music.stop()

        # Сброс слайдера
        self.Slider.set(0)  

    def move_slider(self, value):
        position = float(value)

        # Установка позиции воспроизведения
        mixer.music.set_pos(position)  

    def update_slider(self):
        if mixer.music.get_busy():

            # Получение текущей позиции в секундах
            current_position = mixer.music.get_pos() / 1000
            self.Slider.set(current_position)

            # Обновление слайдера каждую секунду
            self.Slider.after(100, self.update_slider)  

# Отрисовка окна
root = CTk()
set_default_color_theme("dark-blue") 
set_appearance_mode("dark")
app = MusicPlayer(root)
root.mainloop()


добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! как задать хороший вопрос

Я отметил изменения, которые внес в ваш код, проверьте.
from tkinter import *
from customtkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import Scale
from pygame import mixer
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
from PIL import Image, ImageTk


class MusicPlayer():
    def __init__(self, window):
        self.music_file = None
        self.playing_state = False
        mixer.init()                # Инициализация Pygame mixer
        
        window.geometry('330x150')
        window.resizable(0, 0)
        window.title('Music')

#       self.Slider = CTkSlider(
# ---------> v <------------------------------------------------        
        self.slider = CTkSlider(
            window, 
            from_=0, to=100, width=300, 
            command=self.move_slider)
        self.slider.set(0)
        self.slider.place(x=10, y=100)
        
        self.Load = CTkButton(window, text='Load', command=self.load, width=50)
        self.Play = CTkButton(window, text='Play', command=self.play, width=50)
        self.Pause = CTkButton(window, text='Pause', command=self.pause, width=50)
        self.Stop = CTkButton(window, text='Stop', command=self.stop, width=50)
        
        # Расположение
        self.Load.place(x=10, y=20)
        self.Play.place(x=135, y=20)
        self.Pause.place(x=260, y=20)
        self.Stop.place(x=135, y=60)

    # Загрузка файлов
    def load(self):
        try:
            self.music_file = askopenfilename(
                filetypes=[('Audio Files', '*.wav *.ogg *.mp3')])
            if self.music_file:
                self.music_length = mixer.Sound(
                    self.music_file).get_length()  # Получаем длину музыки
                print(f'Сейчас играет: {self.music_file} / {int(self.music_length)}')
                mixer.music.load(self.music_file)  # Загрузка музыки при загрузке файла
                self.slider.configure(             # Установка длины слайдера
                    to=mixer.Sound(self.music_file).get_length())  
                self.slider.set(0)                 # Сброс слайдера
        except Exception as e:
            print(f'Не удалось загрузить файл: {e}')

    # Начать играть песню
    def play(self):
        if self.music_file:
            mixer.music.play()
            mixer.music.set_pos(self.slider.get())             # +++
            # Начать обновление слайдера
            self.update_slider()  

    def pause(self):
        if not self.playing_state:
            mixer.music.pause()
            self.playing_state = True
        else:
            mixer.music.set_pos(self.slider.get())             # +++
            mixer.music.unpause()
            self.playing_state = False
            self.update_slider()

    def stop(self):
        mixer.music.stop()
        self.slider.set(0)  

    def move_slider(self, value):
#?      position = float(value)
        position = int(value)
        
        # Установка позиции воспроизведения
        if mixer.music.get_busy():
            mixer.music.set_pos(position)
        
#        print(f'position = {position} -=- {int(self.slider.get())}') #
#        self.slider.set(position)

    def update_slider(self):
#        print(f'update_slider(self): {mixer.music.get_busy()} -=- {self.slider.get()}') #
        if mixer.music.get_busy():
        
# Получение текущей позиции в секундах                        # !!! +++
# !!! +++            
#           current_position = mixer.music.get_pos() / 1000
            current_position = self.slider.get() + 1          # !!! +++

            self.slider.set(current_position)

# Обновление слайдера каждую секунду 
# --------------------------> ??? <--------------------------???
#           self.Slider.after(100, self.update_slider) 
            self.slider.after(1000, self.update_slider)  

# Отрисовка окна
root = CTk()
set_default_color_theme("dark-blue") 
set_appearance_mode("dark")
app = MusicPlayer(root)
root.mainloop()



Все заработало как я и хотел, спасибо

@user28895318 пожалуйста
